# How far can you push Flex built-in tool-tip functionality?

Tags: apache-flex

Looking at tooltip support in Flex, I've seen you can apply colors and styles to modify the appearance.
Is it possible to do cooler stuff like make tool tips appear with a simple animation like how menus work on modern Windows apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the ToolTipManager class (http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/ToolTipManager.html). It has a "showEffect" property which is what you are looking for I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://blog.flexmonkeypatches.com/the-monkey-index/tooltips/
You'll find A TON of useful tutorials/docs about Flex tooltips !